# How to access SharePoint files and folders from Win8?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am developing a Win8 application that will interface with SharePoint (i.e. open, close, update documents).

How do I access the SharePoint files from Win8, using the Win8 Share Contract or any other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use httpclient to call the rest servicrs exposed by sharepoint and consume the data. If you want to use csom you need to call csom functions from another dll and inclide the dll in your project. You cannot include csom libraries directly in store app.

Csom: client side object model

Comment: What is the difference between the CSOM & REST (different features, complexity?) and how the _api is connected here?

Comment: the syntax and methods are different for different versions of sharepoint (2010 and 2013) for both csom and rest.
_api is used while creating rest urls in sharepoint 2013. the problem with rest with sharepoint is that the documentation on msdn seems inadequate and cluttered. csom would not work directly with win8. you need to write your own library in which you refer to csom dlls and call its functions. csom provides easy manipulation of data in csharp, since everything is exposed as classes and objects.

Answer (score 0):

SkyDrive Pro (comes with Office 2013 I believe) has the ability to create a Library out of your Sharepoints, so they'll act just like any other folder.

On your sharepoint, at the top of a Library should be a button that says "Sync Sharepoint". If you have SkyDrive Pro installed, you should be able to open that and auto-create a library for it.

If you're asking how to do it directly from code (instead of through something like a FileOpenPicker), you'll have to use the Microsoft.Sharepoint namespace and libraries. You can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163980.aspx).